# Regular expression one or more groups - regex to match a url with and without port number

Tags: java, regex, url

I have a regular expression to match a URL

```
(^http.?://\b)(.*):(\d*)(.*)

http://udara.com:8907/phpmyadmin/index.php
```

matches the above expression. However, there may be cases where port is not specified in the URL as below:

```
http://udara.com/phpmyadmin/index.php?token=48bdb70fd4f1e6abe5ecb84192c1835e
```

In this case the expression does not match.

How to say zero or more of the 3rd group.
Note that there may be IPs instead of the domain udara.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following: `(^http.?://([a-zA-Z\-]+)(?::(\d*))?(.*)`

EIDT:

`^http.?://([a-zA-Z\-\.]+)(?::(\\d*))?(.*)` - java

`^http.?:\/\/([a-zA-Z\-\.]+)(?::(\d*))?(.*)` - perl (and regex101.com)

Comment: I am testing online with
http://regex101.com/. Seems regular expression has errors

Note that there may be IPs instead of the domain udara.com

Comment: I took (?::(\d*))? from your comment and add it t my existing expression. Now it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

`http://[a-z\.]+(:[0-9]+)*/.+`